# Apache Tomcat Service Doesn't Recognize JAVA_HOME when installed NSIS - PowerShell Script

Tags: java, powershell, tomcat, nsis

I'm making a NSIS installer for a program that requires Apache Tomcat 8 as Windows Service. JAVA_HOME is set as an environment variable in NSIS installer script, and I've made Powershell Script file to deal with Tomcat specific variables (`CATALINA_HOME, JvmMX, JvmArgs`) and to run `service.bat install` in the end.

When I run the following Powershell script independently (with JAVA_HOME environment variable set) `service.bat install` installs the Tomcat service finding the right correct `JAVA_HOME` path. However, when it's done via installer, as shown in the image below, it gets an empty path for both `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME.`

I'm relying on [psExec.nsh](https://gist.github.com/julianhille/e5f3ee50b11a77c4f77c855ae3d9c443) plug-in to execute Powershell script (`${PowerShellExecFileLog}`)

I don't seem to be able to find why this is happening.. any help would be very appreciated!
My only speculation is that it has something to do with 32-bit/64-bit. I'm confident that I'm wrong so please correct me but here goes my thought: The system is 64-bit and the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is 64-bit, but the installer is 32-bit, making the Powershell it's calling is 32-bit so the Powershell can't retreive the 64-bit environment variable.

Followings are the relevant codes snippets:

```
[PowerShell Script -- Tomcat-Setup.ps1]

$PhysMemory=(Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
$SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE="auto"

if($PhysMemory -le 16) {
    $JvmMX=2048
} elseif($PhysMemory -le 32) {
    $JvmMX=4096
} else {
    $JvmMX=8192
}

$JvmArgs="-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8;-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8;-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError;-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError;-Dconf.home=$env:LGCDM_HOME\conf\service"
$CATALINA_HOME="$env:LGCDM_HOME\apache-tomcat"

Set-Location $CATALINA_HOME
& .\bin\service.bat install LG_Tomcat
Set-Service -Name LG_Tomcat -StartupType Automatic -DisplayName LG_Tomcat
```

```
[NSIS Script]

Section "MainSection" SEC02  
  InitPluginsDir
  ${PowerShellExecFileLog} "$INSTDIR\Tomcat-Setup.ps1"
SectionEnd
```

[image]

Comment: How are you setting JAVA_HOME in NSIS?

Comment: @Anders I'm writing JAVA_HOME value in Windows registry directly. The exact line is as follow: `${registry::Write} "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" "JAVA_HOME" "$INSTDIR\amazon_jdk\jdk11.0.12_7" "REG_EXPAND_SZ" $R0`

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the registry does not affect the installer and any child processes you might start, you should also update the installer process itself:

```
!include "winmessages.nsh"
${registry::Write} ...
SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_WININICHANGE} 0 "STR:Environment" /TIMEOUT=5000
System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "JAVA_HOME", ts)' "$INSTDIR\amazon_jdk\jdk11.0.12_7" ; Update this process
...
; Start Powershell script...
```